# Kafka alway one consumer consume the topic message in one group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have two consumer servers with same group id subscribed the same topic.
A kafka server is running with only one partition.
As far as I know, the message should be consumed randomly in those two consumer servers.
But now it seems to be always the same consumer server A consume messages, another one does not consume messages.If I stop consumer server A, another one will work fine.
What I expect that they can consume message randomly.

Comment: Which factors will affect the consumer server priority? network or something else?

Answer (score 3):

To be able to use two consumer instances in parallel you need at least two partitions in the topic. A consumer will bind to one or more partitions of a topic and other consumers with the same groupId will not claim partitions which already have consumers bound to them. If a consumer fails/crashes, the partition will be released and then picked up by another consumer instance.

Answer (score 0):

Topic partitions are assigned to consumers when it comes up and keep polling the same partition for new messages until consumer dies and another consumer picks up the particular partition. For better throughput, you should have more partitions and consumers but think about sequencing of messages. You may need to follow partition key which will allow the same key messages falling into same partition and giving sequencing guarantee.